# Vertical Lines on Print of Bootstrap Select fields (Chrome/OSX)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

When printing from a page in my app where Bootstrap styles the select fields, the print-outs show vertical lines running down the page either side of it. Just to check, this also happens when you print out the page on the Bootstrap demo site.

This is when using Chrome on OSX, but seems to be fine in other browsers and Chrome on Windows.

Any ideas why/how to fix this?[image]

Answer (score 4):

Add this rule to the print stylesheet (or use a mediaquery):

```
select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

Comment: You might want to make that apply only to print media:

    @media print {
      select { -webkit-appearance: none; }
    }